# how do I remove files when the filename has specific characters from linux folder

Tags: linux

I have a folder of images.

the folder looks like below:

```
dir/
--image1.png
--image1_600x600.png
--image1_1200x1200.png
--image2.png
--image2_600x600.png
```

How do I delete all files that have the 'x' character leaving only the original ones?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find`:

```
find dir -name '*x*' -delete
```

Comment: perfect.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Matching any x in the file name

```
# rm *x*
```

Matching only the x between digits

```
# rm *[0-9]x[0-9]*
```

Both of these presume the shell of course.  If you are using a graphical file manager, you can hold down the Ctrl key as you click on each one you want to delete (Edit -> Delete in Thunar)